# Switch to another presentation with Presentation(x).Window(1).Activate

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have written VBA code to copy slides from one presentation to another.

I activate the Source-Presentation and copy a slide.
Then I switch to the Destination-Presentation and do a PasteSpecial.
When the file is done I save the Destination-Presentation and close it.
The Source is closed as well.
Then I loop to the next file and open both Source and Destination.
This works with two or three files. Then the code gets stuck.

I found while debugging, the activating of the Destination-Presentation is suddenly not working any more.

I'm working with PPT 2010 and Win 7.

The following is the part of the code that gives me problems.
It seems, that the difficulty is the switch from source to destination. The switch from destination to source always worked.
I wrote the macro to get across the limitations of the PPT-Handout format, where pictures are usually too small and you can't position them to be left-oriented and right-oriented to have a good double-sided printout.
This macro is based on the "SlideCopy"-Example by Microsoft which inspired me to try it.

With the Do Loop I start to open the source-files, then the destination-file.
I run the code from a separate (empty) presentation, just containing the code. So in total I will have three presentations running. This is just the part of the code that gives me problems. The total code is a bit big, as I do quite some formatting, you can imagine.

```
For x = 1 To SourceSlides                   'Loop through all the slides of Source and

ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(x)).Select
ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(x)).Copy  'Select the first slide in the presentation and copy it.

SourceCount = SourceCount + 1
Debug.Print "SourceCount = " & SourceCount

If SourceCount = 1 Then                         'window must be visible
    prDst.Windows(1).Activate                   ' Switch to destination presentation. <-- The problem!!
    oPpt.Visible = msoTrue
    ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (n)             'Switch to the proper slide.
    ActivePresentation.Slides(n).Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)  ' Paste the slide as Shape

    If PasteLeftRight = 0 Then                  ' Adjust the size of the pasted object.
        ActivePresentation.Slides(n).Shapes(1).Select
        Paste_1_Right
    Else
        ActivePresentation.Slides(n).Shapes(1).Select
        Paste_1_Left
    End If

Else
    prDst.Windows(1).Activate       '<-- The other Problem!!
    oPpt.Visible = msoTrue

    ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (n) 'Index:=ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    ActivePresentation.Slides(n).Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)  ' Paste the slide.

    If PasteLeftRight = 0 Then                              ' Adjust the size of the pasted object.
        ActivePresentation.Slides(n).Shapes(2).Select
        Paste_2_Right
        PasteLeftRight = 1
    Else
        ActivePresentation.Slides(n).Shapes(2).Select
        Paste_2_Left
        PasteLeftRight = 0
    End If
    If x = SourceSlides Then
    Debug.Print "x = " & x
    Else
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Add _
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank
    End If

    SourceCount = 0
    n = n + 1

End If

' Unselect the object.
ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect

' Switch to source.
prSrc.Windows(1).Activate
oPpt.Visible = msoTrue
If ActiveWindow.ViewType <> ppViewSlideSorter Then
   ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlideSorter
End If

Next x
.
.
.
```

Comment: Show your actual code.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't have any Windows. Check: `prDst.Windows.count`

Comment: Maybe your presentation doesn't have a window, so you need to open a new window instead of activating a window.

`if YourPowerPointPresentation.Windows.count > 0 then YourPowerPointPresentation.Windows(1).Activate else YourPowerPointPresentation.NewWindow end if`

Hard to say without the complete code.